# Calling a method from a JButton is freezing a JFrame?

Tags: java, swing, jframe, jbutton, event-dispatch-thread

I'm doing a basic Pong game for a class. I have the Pong working, and I have a GUI display on startup, unfortunately I can't seem to start the game from the start JButton. I've commented where the problem is on the code, and removed irrelevant code.

```
 frame.add(GUIPanel);
        JButton startButton = new JButton("Start!");     
        GUIPanel.add(startButton, BorderLayout.CENTER);
        startButton.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
            public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e)
         { 
             frame.getContentPane().remove(GUIPanel);
             frame.validate();
             frame.repaint();

             drawPanel = new DrawPanel();
             drawPanel.requestFocus();
             frame.getContentPane().add(BorderLayout.CENTER, drawPanel);
              //This is the part that freezes it, everything else works fine
              //except that the playGame method isn't called. If I remove the whole
              //startButton and whatnot I can call playGame and it works perfectly.                                                                                    
              playGame();          
           }
         }); 
         }
```

any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Swing is a single threaded framework.

That is, all interactions and modifications to the UI are to be made from within the context of the Event Dispatching Thread.  Anything that blocks this thread will prevent it from processing, amongst other things, repaint requests and user input/interactions.

My guess is that `playGame` is using something like `Thread.sleep` or some kind of `while(true)` and is blocking the EDT, causing your program to appear as if it's frozen

Have a read through [Concurrency in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/concurrency/) for more details.

A simple solution would be to use a [Swing `Timer`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/misc/timer.html) to act as you game loop.  Each time it ticks, you would update the state of your game and call (something like) `repaint` on you game's component

Comment: Oh my god thank you so much. I was hesitant to ask on here just to avoid wasting people's time, but you've saved me an hour or two at the very least! I'll be sure to accept your answer when I can!

Comment: +1 for @MadProgrammer programmer's mad Programming yaar m really shocked u know this much please do me one favor. give me studentship be my teacher bro . ;)

Comment: @Krishna The main reason I know this stuff is I've made these mistakes myself before ;)

Comment: @MadProgrammer but still u are great. :) u did much time code for me. and thank you very much bro :)  and ya even i want to know this much too :)

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you've got a parenthesis that doesn't belong next to your second to last semicolon. Try removing it.

Comment: It does look wrong haha. It's actually the end to the addActionListener( parenthesis. But thanks anyway!

Comment: Oh, I missed that. Sorry.

Comment: Not a problem, just taking the time to read through and try to help others makes you awesome in my book!